# Barcode submit form

Tags: php, barcode

Is it possible to create barcode to submit HTML form and do MySQL update via PHP? I've never done something like that, but currently I'm building some application that will track job done in some Injection Mold company. Can I use mobile barcode scanner or we need dedicated barcode scanner? First, I thought about barcode that will automatically open URL in form like this

```
https://example.com/verif.php?pos=12&op=10&true=1
```

And that link will submit form I want. Or something like barcode scanner directly submit form without opening URL? I need advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with barcode scanners before.  The barcode represents a string, and all that the scanner will do is read and paste it onto whatever format you have on the computer, in my case, it was on excel sheets, a field in an app, etc.  Your scanner will come with a program where you can customize the action upon scanning.

You can definitely use a mobile scanner.

If you want it to submit a form without opening URL, you need to create a form submission platform, which needs to automatically submit and automate that process.  Speed can be a key depending on how quickly you expect to scan.